# DD/MM/YYYY regex equivalent in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

How can I get javascript regex check against a input value? the same way I do in php:

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/", $_POST['date']) === 0)
```

It must ONLY validate DD/MM/YYYY and should not except D/M/YYYY. my php code does not allow D/M/YYYY, only allows DD/MM/YYYY, it needs to be this strict for the integration I am doing.

Updated Code: but keeps returning false :/

```
//Date must ONLY be DD/MM/YYYY
jQuery.validator.addMethod("strictDate", function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    var patt = new RegExp("/^((0[1-9])|([12][1-9])|(3[01]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((19[0-9]{2})|(2[0-9]{3}))$/");

    if (patt.test(value)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}, "Date must be in the following format DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Comment: Did you even try it... The same regex works in JS too.

Comment: But your given regex will accept invalid date as well e.g. 41/43/9999

Comment: I have updated my test but it is not working correctly.

Comment: its working  c.had 1990

Comment: should I not use additional method DateITA from additional-methods.js now that I am using my own regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Its working like 05/05/2005 not 5/05/2005

and working like 05/05/2005 not 05/5/2005

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Date Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isValidDate(sText) {
        var reDate = /(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19|20\d{2})/;
        return reDate.test(sText);
    }
    function validate() {
        var oInput1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
        if (isValidDate(oInput1.value)) {
            alert("Valid");
        } else {
            alert("Invalid!");
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <P>Date: <input type="text" id="txt1" /><br />
    example: 05/05/2005<br />
    <input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validate()" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

http://js.do/code/65207

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I think it needs just a little correction, `/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19\d{2}|20\d{2})/`, with the group \d{2} even after the 19 for the year part, otherwise it could accept dates with just one digit after 19, eg. 20/09/191, if the year is one between 1900 and 1999

Comment: We need to add a $ symbol at the end too, to indicate the string termination, `/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19\d{2}|20\d{2})$/`, or it would accept even dates with 5 or more digits in the year part, for example 20/09/20189

Answer (score 1):

This is the way in JS:

```
string='moshe';
if (string.match("/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/)){
}
```

There is another way

```
var reg=new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$")
bool=reg.test('12/33/1234')  //true
```

And a working demo:

```js
function check(){
  
  alert('The value is date (true/null):' + abc.value.match(/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/))
  }
```

```html
Enter Data:<input id=abc>

<button onclick=check()>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex you pasted does not validate the days, month and years correctly. I modified it to take dd/mm/yyyy,dd-mm-yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy. If you only want / sperated dates then use `\/` in place of `\/|-|\.` in the code.

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

**EDIT:**

Your regx : `/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/`

1. `^[0-9]{2}` means it will accept all numbers till 99.
2. `[0-9]{4}$` means it will accept all numbers till 9999.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a regex like this:

```
^((0[1-9])|([12][1-9])|(3[01]))\/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((19[0-9]{2})|(2[0-9]{3}))$
```

That validates strings from `01/01/1900` to `31/12/2999`.